# Can I say: She looks so perfectly happy?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, so

Can I use that structure: SO + ADVERB + ADJECTIVE. 
Does it make sense? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It seems so. There are many such examples in [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q="so+perfectly+happy"&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the construction "so"+adverb+adjective is so perfectly fine, that you can use it to really drive home the adjective

> so wonderfully delicious
>   so maddeningly red
>   so artificially sweet
>   so intensely sour
>   so boringly *(,well,)* boring

One does need to be aware of heaping superlative upon superlative

> She looks *so perfectly happy*
>   She looks *so very much incredibly happy* with her teddy bear, I dare not take it away.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [so](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so) in this way, it is a modifier meaning **very** and can be applied to adverbs **so slowly** and adjectives **so happy**.

It can also be used as a modifier for an adverb that modifies an adjective **so very happy**, although usage of this construction has been [steadily declining](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so%20very%2C%20so%20perfectly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20perfectly%3B%2Cc0)- maybe because it is perceived as exaggerated- **so very happy** is like saying **very very happy**.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are so definitely correct.